# Cretae Domains Table In HSQL includes the metadata of Domains Sytem View

Tags: hsqldb

I want to create a table named Domains in HSQL. But when i try to do so it includes 29 columns although my table definition specifies just 5.There is a Domains System View and it seems it is including these columns also in my metadata.Because of this i am not able to insert anything in my db as those unwanted columns from Domains System View also contain some non-null values.
I tried creating schema but it is not what i need as my solution.
I need to override this Domains System View or stop the metadata from picking it.

Does anyone know how can we do it?
I am stuck at it for more than few days now.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Domains
(
    domain_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    CREATED_BY VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    LAST_UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (domain_id)
);
```

Comment: Please show the DDL (`create table`) and the `SELECT` you are using.

Comment: This is the create table statement : CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Domains(domain_id INTEGER NOT NULL,name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,description VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,CREATED_BY VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,LAST_UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (domain_id))

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question.

Comment: Works for me. How exactly does the SELECT look like.